# UITableView handler for cell will hide

Tags: ios, swift

The `UITableViewDelegate` has a convenient function, [`willDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview).

I need to add a handler for when a cell hides, which is essentially the opposite of `willDisplay`. How can I detect this event?

Comment: Did you try to use `willMoveToSuperview` in the cell's subclass? In it's implementation you can call your custom callback

Comment: Can you use `prepareForReuse`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you'll want to use is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview)